# Por qué no muestra el contenido con ajax

Tags: ajax

Quiero que muestre un mensaje pero me sale esto :

> ReferenceError: __ is not defined _______  goLogin/connect.onreadystatechange

*Generales.js*

```
    function __(id){
      return document.getElementById(id);
   }
```

//-----------------------------

```
<div id="_AJAX_LOGIN_"></div>  
<script src="views/app/js/login.js"></script>

function goLogin() {
      // window.alert('Se presiono ENTER');
      var connect, form, response, result;
      form = 'variable=contenido';
      connect = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

      connect.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (connect.readyState == 4 && connect.status == 200) {
          if (connect.responseText == 1) {
            result = '<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success">';
            result += '<h4>Conectado</h4>';
            result += '<p><strong>Estamos Redireccionandote...</strong></p>';
            result += '</div>';
            __('_AJAX_LOGIN_').innerHTML = result;
            location.reload();

          }else{
            __('_AJAX_LOGIN_').innerHTML = connect.responseText;
          }
        }else if (connect.readyState != 4){
          result = '<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-warning">';
          result += '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">X</button>';
          result += '<h4>Procesando...</h4>';
          result += '<p><strong>Estamos intentando Logearte...</strong></p>';
          result += '</div>';
        }
      }
      connect.open('POST','ajax.php?mode=login',true);
      connect.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      connect.send(form);
    }//FIn de goLogin
```

Comment: quien me ayuda porfa

Comment: hola una pregunta no te seria mas cómodo usar **jquery**

Comment: estoy practicando de distintas formas

Comment: Si lo haces como estudio ok pero con jquery es muy como y rápido y también el # de error es menor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reemplaza:

```
__('_AJAX_LOGIN_').innerHTML
```

Por:

```
document.getElementById('_AJAX_LOGIN_').innerHTML
```

Comment: si asi me funciona pero yo tengo una funcion que almacena document.getElementById asi:  .. :  function __(id){
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

Comment: No la veo en tu pregunta.

Comment: posiblemente no llame a ese js

Comment: listo, el problema era que meti el codigo en otro js con el mismo nombre pero direcciones distintas esto se debe a que estoy empesando a costumbrarme a MVC

Comment: gracias...................

Comment: De nada hermano, estamos para servir :D éxitos con el desarrollo!